# Binomial Formula conversion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I saw an answer in stackoverflow about binomial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929897/1545363)
The answerer provide some nice explanation how can binomial can be calculated by pascal triangle.
But I'm still not sure how to convert this

```
       N!                   N!               N!      (N-K)
---------------- = -------------------- = -------- x -----
 (N-K-1)! (K+1)!   (N-K)!/(N-K) K!(K+1)   (N-K)!K!   (K+1)
```

And then the correlation with this

```
(N choose K+1) = (N choose K) * (N-K)/(K+1)
```

and this

```
 N!
---- = 1
N!0!
```

with pascal triangle?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You should learn mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . It is what we use to format our maths. it changes x^2+sqrt(y) to $x^2+\sqrt{y}$

Comment: @Joao Wow never know about it! I'm new in here but will try to edit it later! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question you refer to shows how to compute a function which computes $\binom{a}{b}$ recursively instead of using the definition of $\binom{a}{b}$.

Instead of using the definition

$$
\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n!}{(n-(k+1))!(k+1)!}
$$

one can do

$$
\binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} \frac{n-(k+1)+1}{k+1}
$$

so one must calculate the same function but for $k$ instead of $k+1$. One can apply the same formula replacing $k+1$ by $k$

$$
\binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} \frac{n-(k+1)+1}{k+1}
 = \bigg( \binom{n}{k-1} \frac{n-k+1}{k}\bigg) \frac{n-(k+1)+1}{k+1}
$$

and now you get $k-1$, so every time you get the same function but with one of the variables decreasing by one.

This is easy to give to a computer, but it must stop somewhere. To do that, one has that by definition
$$
\binom{n}{k-k}=\binom{n}{0}=\frac{n!}{(n-0)!0!}=\frac{n!}{n!1}
$$
so $\binom{n}{0}$ does not depend on $\binom{n}{-1}$.

To put it short, Pascal's triangle is an array where the $n$-th floor has $\binom{n}{0}$ up to $\binom{n}{n}$